# Controls set to transparent look like this?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a groupbox and panel control on my winform. I have them set to backcolor = transparent. Why does it look fine on my dev computer but when on another computer it the background of it look like this?

[image]

Comment: 8 bit colour or vga mode?

Comment: whatt  you mean, the panel/group box background just have that look on it, the picture box if i add it to the form will look fine. i'm not sure why, all monitors are vga connected and should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably facing a limitation of .net.  It doesn't allow true transparency, just some tricks to make it look transparent.  If you want true transparency take a look at WPF.